# Twitter bootstrap progress bar percentage label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a Twitter bootstrap progressbar and put them inside a table.
But when percentages are low, label can't be seen like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/w48qH/4/

Regarding to this, adding `min-width` is recommended: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-label

But adding min-width makes progress bar lengths illogical, all bar lengths becomes same: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/w48qH/7/

Also table columns are very far away from each other in big screens. There is too much space between first column and second column.

What would be the better way to show progress bar for small percentages ? And better layout for table ?

Answer (score 4):

**Simply** add this to your CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
    overflow-x:visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:black; /* color is for demo purposes */
}
```

No need to edit the HTML.

This shows the label without compromising the progress bar's progressed color part.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w48qH/9/

Comment: @icfantv Thanks for mentioning the dead link. I changed it to a working link.

Answer (score 0):

I think the min-width might be meant for the content inside of the progress bar. So take a look at my example built upon your fiddle:

html:

```
<div class="progresslabel"> % 12</div><br>
```

css:

```
.progresslabel{

    min-width:40px;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.progresslabel').each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > $(this).parent().width()){
     $(this).css("color","black");   
    }
});
```

Now this of course looks bad but it's just an example you can do whatever you want with it but I hope you get the idea.

Here is a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fLk8/3/

Answer (score 0):

@Arbel answer is highly underrated. I checked a lot of stackoverflow posts until finding his answer.

It is also important to add !important in the changes he suggested, otherwise the code won't work (In my work, using react bootstrap it didn't until adding !important)

Comment: This does not really provide an answer to the question. You can better vote on Arbel's answer or the question itself.

Comment: Furthermore `!important` is as usually a bad practice, better use a selector with a greater level of [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) and might be only an individual problem.